# pybind11 for classes initialized with custom variables

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am new to pybind11 and I am using it to implement some C++ functions and classes in python. Reading the documentation, I understand how to implement classes where standard types are passed as variables in the constructor. I cannot find how to pass custom variables.

#### Simple example and solution

The first easier example is:

```
struct Vec {
    float x, y, z;    
    Vec(float x_ = 0, float y_ = 0, float z_ = 0) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
        z = z_;
    }
    float func(const int &b) const {
        return x * b.x + y * b.y + z * b.z;
    }
```

To import this in python, I would do (and hopefully it's correct):

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(some_module, m) {

    py::class_<Vec>(m, "Vec");
        .def(py::init<float, float, float>())
        .def("func", &Vec::func)
}
```

#### Question

Now, if my constructor doesn't take `float` and `int`, how can I do that? I'll show an example:

```
class Rectangle_xz {
public:
    float x1, x2, z1, z2, y;
    Vec e, c;        
    Refl_t refl;      
    Rectangle_xz(float x1_, float x2_, float z1_, float z2_, float y_,
            Vec e_, Vec c_, Refl_t refl_) :
            x1(x1_), x2(x2_), z1(z1_), z2(z2_), y(y_), e(e_), c(c_), refl(refl_) {}
}
```

In this case, my constructor needs two different types, `Vec` and `Refl_t`. 
Similar question for those functions that accept a custom type:

```
Vec normal(const Ray &r, Hit_records &hit, Vec &x) const {
        Vec n = Vec(0, 1, 0);
        hit.refl = refl;
        hit.c = c;
        hit.e = e;
        return n.dot(r.d) < 0 ? n : n * -1;
    }
```

#### EDIT

I tried with a simple example, to see if after initializing a class, I could pass that class as a variable.

```
class Person {
public:
    int a, b;
    Person(int a_, int b_) :
        a(a_), b(b_){}  
};

class Gatto {
public:
    Person p1;
    Gatto(Person p1_) : 
        p1(p1_){}   };

PYBIND11_MODULE(person_example, m) {
    py::class_<Person>(m, "Person")
        .def(py::init<int, int>())
        .def_readwrite("a", &Person::a)
        .def_readwrite("b", &Person::b);

    py::class_<Gatto>(m, "Gatto")
        .def(py::init<&Person>())
        .def_readwrite("p1", &Gatto::p1);
}
```

This now works, but I cannot get the `a` and `b` variables from `Gatto`, when I pass the `Person` object to its constructor. Indeed, `Gatto` only has the variable `p1`, which returns the pointer to the object `Person`.

Comment: For the first case I can suspect you can make pybind aware of `Vec` and `Refl_t` first and then add `Rectangle_xz` with `py::init<float, float, float, float, float, Vec, Vec, Refl_t>`?

Comment: @Botje I added an EDIT, if that what you meant.

Comment: You never linked `a` and `b` to `Gatto`, so why would you expect that to work? I would expect `gatto.p1.a` to work though..